# What (if any) are the risks of renaming and domain-joining a machine at the same time?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

Just a quick, basic question, on account of a difference of opinion I'm having.

When joining a new [Windows] machine to an Active Directory domain, what risks are there if the rename and the domain join are done at the same time?  (As opposed to renaming the machine, rebooting, joining to the domain and rebooting).

On the off chance it matters, this is a 2003 Functional Level domain and forest, and concerns client machines  that are primarily XP and servers that are primarily Server 2008 R2.

Bonus points (bounty!) if anyone knows of a documented Microsoft Best Practice or recommendation for whether or not to do this in one reboot or two.

Comment: Good question, simply because "tradition" usually takes over here vs. fact.  For me, I've run into similar trust relationship issues like Evan states, so just as practice I've renamed, reboot, join, reboot.  But interesting that you ask since just the other day I did both at the same time and it worked fine (on a 2008R2 server build).  I wonder if the caveat is more for 2003/XP and newer OS' handle it fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't find a specific Windows Vista or newer related article, but I think this would count as canonical documentation: [How to change a computer name, join a domain, and add a computer description in Windows XP or in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295017/en-us). This documentation indicates that you can modify the computer name *and* domain at the same time (and doesn't caution against it).

I suspect you're dealing with someone who has the same superstition that I've had over the years: Change the computer name, reboot, then join the domain.

I know that I've seen instances where doing that has ended up with a broken domain trust relationship on the client computer. I never documented the specific workflow necessary to create that undesirable scenario. My pragmatic streak kicked-in and just caused me to rename, reboot, and then join. For fun, I may try to do some replication in a VM.

Edit:

I had a few minutes for some VM testing fun.

I two really simple tests on a Windows XP Professional SP3 VM, starting fresh from a template configured in a workgroup.

- Changed computer name and domain together, provided domain credential, received dialog indicating that domain join succeeded, rebooted, and found that I had a good domain trust relationship.
- Joined domain, provided domain credential, received dialog indicating that domain join succeeded, clicked "Change" button in "System Properties" dialog again, changed computer name, provided domain credential, rebooted, and found that I had a good domain trust relationship.

Obviously there are possible permutations if you bring in dodgy DC replication into play, changing the domain trust relationship with a command-line tool like `netdom`, and probably a whole host of other factors that could influence. In general, though, it looks like Windows XP (and likely every follow-on Windows version) can handle the change to both the computer name and the domain trust relationship together without a reboot between.

I'll probably still reboot between, personally.

Comment: Thanks.  I do remember it causing some problems back in the NT4/Win2k days (but then again, what didn't?), so I'm pretty sure I know where the `name, reboot, join reboot` process comes from, but finding anything official on the topic was like pulling teeth.

Comment: `"for fun"` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: This is a new emoticon for me. I am enjoying it.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to reboot after both the rename and the domain join.

With XP, you have the ability to rename and then go back to the options to join the PC to the domain. Windows 7 will instead (almost always) gray out the domain option after renaming.

As far as risk, I'd venture to say you run the risk of adding the PC with the old PC name, or worse an incorrect SID. If you like to rename and join without several reboots on 7, I'd suggest testing with the netdom.exe command.

Netdom - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I don't get your "equation", just use English instead.

Comment: Thank you for the edit longneck. gparent, I hope you can understand what I attempted to rely better now that the post has been edited.

Comment: What's the point of avoiding English? I submitted an edit that doesn't needlessly transform text into maths.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but since it still comes up on google.. this is no longer voodoo:

Rename PC, join domain, reboot.

You don't join, rename, reboot because you want to be sure that the computer and DC have agreed on a computer account password so that the computer is allowed to tell the DC that its name has changed. Rebooting after you join the domain assures that this step is completed.

For example you do Not need to reboot between leaving the domain, renaming your computer, and then rejoining the domain (now reboot). You can leave-rename-join-reboot. The reason is that you have no AD computer account to worry about after you leave, and when you reboot after rejoin you will be rebooting into the computer account you just created on the DC.